# Google app engine python problem

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having a problem with the datastore trying to replicate a left join to find items from model a that don't have a matching relation in model b:

```
class Page(db.Model):
    url = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Item(db.Model):
    page = db.ReferenceProperty(Page, required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

I want to find any pages that don't have any associated items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot query for items using a "property is null" filter. However, you can add a boolean property to Page that signals if it has items or not:

```
class Page(db.Model):
    url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    has_items = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

Then override the "put" method of Item to flip the flag. But you might want to encapsulate this logic in the Page model (maybe Page.add_item(self, *args, **kwargs)):

```
class Item(db.Model):
    page = db.ReferenceProperty(Page, required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

    def put(self):
        if not self.page.has_items:
            self.page.has_items = True
            self.page.put()
        return db.put(self)
```

Hence, the query for pages with no items would be:

```
pages_with_no_items = Page.all().filter("has_items =", False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The datastore doesn't support joins, so you can't do this with a single query. You need to do a query for items in A, then for each, do another query to determine if it has any matching items in B.

Comment: Ok, I assumed there would be a way to do this in the datastore, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try it like :

```
Page.all().filter("item_set = ", None)
```

Should work.

Comment: Also tried .filter("item_set.count() = ", 0)

In both cases nothing is returned (one of the records should be returned).